# Where can I find Markdown language documentation?

Tags: github, markdown

I just a newbie on github. I'm doing my Project with the Markdown file type on that. So, can you show me where can I find full of Markdown Documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Markdown is a lightweight and easy-to-use syntax for styling all forms of writing on the GitHub platform.
You can find this:
https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/

Answer (score 0):

The best place to learn about markdown would be https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/

Answer (score 0):

Another Markdown reference I have found useful is https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax . This documentation gives reference to Markdown code next to HTML code that helps users understand the syntax more easily if they are familiar with HTML and its outputs.